# route added, but shows inverse ip

Tags: dns, ip, route

Using xubuntu...
i'm trying to add a route in my work laptop, and so i do

```
route add -host 212.18.178.207 gw 10.15.228.1 eth0
```

for some strange reason, when i do just route, this is what i get...

```
207.178.18.212. 10.15.228.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

what's with the address inversion? and that extra . ?

This still works, i'm just curious as to why it got inverted...

Comment: I'm curious too, this is in fact a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

That's the reverse DNS PTR record, or a portion of it. By default `route` will try and lookup the name of an IP address. `route -n` will not try to resolve hostnames and give you the plain IP address.

Even better use [`ip`](http://lartc.org/manpages/ip.html) from the [iproute2 tools](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.iproute2.html) as they have replaced most of the various `net-tools` commands.

```
ip ro sh
```

The full DNS record is actually [`207.178.18.212.rev.vodafone.pt`](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3A212.18.178.207).

A trailing `.` on a DNS name would normally mean don't add anything else on, this is it (fully qualified). I would lean towards the field being truncated, but maybe your local domain is set to `rev.vodafone.pt` and `route` is leaving it out. Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` for a [`domain`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf) entry.

The reverse naming follows the standard for the [`IN-ADDR.ARPA`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#page-22) domain that is used for reverse lookups. The numbers are reversed so that complete network ranges can be configured and delegated to a DNS server.

`212.in-addr.arpa` whole 212.x.x.x range could be delegated to vodafone.
`18.212.in-addr.arpa` for 212.18.x.x
`178.18.212.in-addr.arpa` for 212.18.178.x

Vodafone have happened to follow that reverse naming standard, even though they could choose any name for the IP address.

Comment: in that case you explain the trailling dot, but what about the fact ip are invertedD ?

Comment: Added a bit about where the reversed IP's comes from in reverse DNS lookups.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand the same question, route instead of showing `dest mask => gw shows `dest ==> gw mask`

Comment: `route` on Linux shows `Destination  Gateway  Genmask`